# From a bash script in OS X, is it possible to prompt for Administrator permissions?

Tags: bash, scripting, permissions, applescript

I have a shell script that adds a line to /etc/hosts. If I run it manually with sudo, it works correctly. I'd like to distribute this file to my coworkers who use Macs. However, when the shell script runs normally, I get a:

```
sed: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Is there a way to force a bash script to prompt for a password, as compiled ObjC code can do? If Bash can't do this, can Applescript do so?

Comment: Can't you call it as `sudo sed ...` from the script?

Comment: It's not run from the Terminal, it's app-ified, inside the folder.app/Contents/MacOS directory. So no, it can't.

Comment: There is an equivalent of `gksudo` called cocoasudo you can try.

Comment: See [this previous answer on apple.se](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23494/what-option-should-i-give-the-sudo-command-to-have-the-password-asked-trough-gra/23514#23514).

Answer (score 4):

Adayzdone's answer is a correct way to use "with administrator privileges"

But you do not need to hard code password or create your own dialog.

If you do not include the user name and password you will be prompted with the standard username and password dialogue for an admin.

```
do shell script "echo hi" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 3):

your shell script can call sudo which would ask at terminal for a password.

Try http://www.performantdesign.com/2009/10/26/cocoasudo-a-graphical-cocoa-based-alternative-to-sudo/

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$SUDO_USER" ]
then
  sed `do stuff`
else    
 cocoasudo --prompt="Please authenticate" bash -l -c "/path/to/this/script"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

With Applescript:

```
property usr : "username"
property pswd : "password"

do shell script "echo hi" user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

Or if you don't want to hard code the password:

```
set usr to text returned of (display dialog "Enter username" default answer "my username")
set pswd to text returned of (display dialog "Enter password…" default answer "my password")

do shell script "echo hi" user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

Comment: probably best not to embed credentials